# ng-bind-html doesn't connect different things in once (not even with $sce.trustAsHtml() )

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-select

I am trying to connect some different html code to my view with ng-bind-html.

I already added `ngSanitize`

Firstly I am using `ng-for`  by `ui-select-choices`

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="test in dataTest>
```

. and I want to bind `test.name` with some Html

`<small> ( {{ TEST_BTN | translate }}) </small>`

The *Test_BTN* is being used for Translation purpose  there fore I can't leave it  out from code.

when I try to use them all in `ng-bind-html`  nothing will be shown

when I try to use them all in `ng-bind` the html code will be shown.

when I try to use `ng-bind` and`ng-bind-html` seperetly , `ng-bind-html` html  won't be shown.

How am I suppose to fix this?

EDIT : I am trying to show the result in a new div  with `ng-if`

something like : `<div data-ng-if="test.isSomething" ng-bind="test.name"  ng-bind-html="' <small>({{'BTN_ADD' | translate}})</small>'" ></div>` (Which doesnt show the `ng-bind-html` part )

EDIT 2 :

I deleted the   `{{ }}` from `data-ng-bind-html`  and used the translation explicitly with the `$translate` service in my controller.

And It worked.

Comment: You shouldn't use `{{}}` inside an `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: But then again, how am I suppose to take ({{'BTN_ADD' | translate}}) in my code, in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-html` on the same element, and you can't use `{{}}` in either one of them.  It's not necessary to concatenate the `<small>` tag inside the `ng-bind-html`, it should be in the template itself.  And you have some syntax error nested-quotes issues in your ng-bind-html clause.

It's not clear to me from your description which of `test.name`, `TEST_BTN` or `BTN_ADD` you actually intend to use; I'm going to assume you really want `test.name` here but if one of those other variables contains the HTML you're trying to embed, just substitute its name in place of test.name:

```
<div ng-if="test.isSomething">
  <small ng-bind-html="test.name | translate"></small>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel , even tho. I didnt use this solution : you gave me the idea, what to change. After reading your comment, I deleted {{}} and translated the button explicitly and then It worked. Thanks a lot.